# Joining Two databases on same server

Tags: sql-server, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZswRK.png)I'm facing some weird problem off late, when i try to write a query on joining two different table located in two different databases on same server i get an error.

For EX: if i select Database A separately data is getting displayed and i have to manually select database from available databases dropdown on the top left.

If i select Database B then i should manually change it back to Database B on available database dropdown, due to this issue I'm not able join two tables together. Please help me in getting settings right.

Comment: can you show your `query` ?

Comment: Screenshots? Something?

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name"Databse name"

Comment: need to see the code and the two database names as well. Have you got a `using` statement in there?

Comment: If i run the query to pull the data on individual database its working but i need to change the data base manually on available database

Comment: select distinct [Material_Number] from [dbo].[view_sku_universe_from_sku_data_quality] T1
 ⁃ left join [dbo].[table_Mat_Deter_SWM] T2 
 ⁃ on T1.[Material_Number]=T2.[Sub_Material_1]
 ⁃ left join [dbo].[table_Mat_Deter_SWM] T3
 ⁃ on T1.[Material_Number]=T3.[Sub_Material_2]
 ⁃ where T2.[Sub_Material_1] is not null or T3.[Sub_Material_2] is not null

Comment: explain to us which tables / views are in which database. Place the database name in front of each table e.g. if your databases are called "DB1" and "DB2" then `...from [DB1].[dbo].[view_sku_universe_from_sku_data_quality]` and similar for tables which are from DB2. (This is just for example, obviously you should use your real database names)

Answer (score 2):

You can use by adding database name before the table name.

```
Select * from Database1.[dbo].Table1 t1
join Database2.[dbo].Table2 t2 on t1.columnName = t2.columnName
```

From Your Query lets T1 from DatabaseA and Remaining From DatabaseB

```
select distinct [Material_Number] from DatabaseA.[dbo].[view_sku_universe_from_sku_data_quality] T1 
    left join DatabaseB.[dbo].[table_Mat_Deter_SWM] T2 on T1.[Material_Number]=T2.[Sub_Material_1] 
    left join DatabaseB.[dbo].[table_Mat_Deter_SWM] T3 on T1.[Material_Number]=T3.[Sub_Material_2]
    where T2.[Sub_Material_1] is not null or T3.[Sub_Material_2] is not null
```

Comment: i tried it but I'm able to run one database at a time, not able to join two databases. Individually it works only if i select the database manually on Availabel databases dropdown.

Comment: @venkyps I have now given your query with T1 is on DatabaseA and T2, T3 on DatabaseB.

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Invalid object name 'DatabaseA.dbo.view_sku_universe_from_sku_data_quality'.

Comment: @venkyps Change name of database to your database names

Comment: @venkyps did it work for you. If yes then accept the answer so that it will help for anyone having a similar question. If you have got any error still then comment to get help

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a user which have rights to access both Databases

2.Login to SSMS from that user which you created (user which have rights to access both Databases).

3.Create query like this

SELECT * FROM TestDatabase1.[dbo].Test1 t1

JOIN TestDatabase2.[dbo].Test2 t2 on t1.TestID= t2.TestID